# Updating UITableView with changing section rows through KVO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, key-value-observing

I have successfully implemented `KVO` between my data singleton and my UITableView. It is observing a `@property`. The tableview correctly adds, removes and updates rows.

I recently added sections to my table (based on a category for each item in the array). The tableview loads properly, I have an array of sections and then my code loops through the `KVO` property to populate those sections.

However, whenever I edit one of those rows (and it moves into a different section), the app crashes complaining that I have an invalid number of rows in section X.

Is there additional logic needed for `KVO` to properly manage changing section lengths and rows? My fairly generic `observeValueForKeyPath` method is below. I tried adding methods for insertSections, deleteSections, and reloadSections in the switch statement but that did not help. Any advice appreciated.

My section is always 0 as I make `NSIndexPath`s, however I can't figure out how to determine the new section with the method's arguments.

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (object == [DataStore sharedInstance] && [keyPath isEqualToString:kPropertyObserved]) {
        NSKeyValueChange kindOfChange = [change[NSKeyValueChangeKindKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
        if (kindOfChange == NSKeyValueChangeSetting) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else if (kindOfChange == NSKeyValueChangeInsertion ||
                   kindOfChange == NSKeyValueChangeRemoval ||
                   kindOfChange == NSKeyValueChangeReplacement){

            NSIndexSet *indexSetOfChanges = change[NSKeyValueChangeIndexesKey];
            NSMutableArray *indexPathsThatChanged = [NSMutableArray new];
            [indexSetOfChanges enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:0];
                [indexPathsThatChanged addObject:newIndexPath];
            }];

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            switch (kindOfChange) {
                case NSKeyValueChangeInsertion:
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsThatChanged withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                    break;
                case NSKeyValueChangeRemoval:
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsThatChanged withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                    break;
                case NSKeyValueChangeReplacement:
                    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsThatChanged withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use the index in `NSKeyValueChangeIndexesKey` and I can figure out which section it should be inserted into, however I can't see which section I need to take it out of. I tried using the option `NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld` but when I log the value after I make the change, it only shows the new value.

Comment: Indeed when i use both options `(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew)`, both entries in the `change` dictionary are identical (`change[NSKeyValueChangeOldKey]` and `change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]`).

Comment: I ended up using `[self.tableView reloadData]` for the replacements or insertions (users can't see the table view at that point anyway). For deleting I made a property of `NSIndexPath` that the `KVO` method reads for deletions. It works but would like to see any other better implementations as well.